# Facebook request does not return email

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

No email is outputted from the Facebook request. How do I get this? I need it for my login/signup process

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result{

    NSLog(@"FACEBOOK RESULT %@ ", result);

}
```

This is the initial request:

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andDelegate:self];
```

Comment: A `FBRequest` can be for many types of requests to Facebook, so depending on what your actual request was will determine was your `result` object is going to contain.  You'll need to provide much more details on the actual request to determine why you aren't getting the information you expect back.

Comment: Updated. Please reconsider the question and take off the -1 if that was you thanks!

Comment: Did you have the `email` permission when you first connected the user to FB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `email` property cannot be obtained without requesting additional permission to obtain it, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/email-permissions/.

My application uses the following code to first check whether the Facebook session is valid (`self.facebook` is a `Facebook` object initialized with `initWithAppId`):

```
  if (![self.facebook isSessionValid]) { 

    NSArray* permissions =  [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"email", nil];

    [self.facebook authorize:permissions];

  } else { 
    // Since we have a valid session we can get the userinfo
    [self getFacebookUserInfo];
  }
```

Your application prompt will indicate "Using this app requires:  * Your basic info * Your e-mail address"  If the user authorizes you to obtain this information your access token returned will have bits in set to allow you to obtain the e-mail address, and the following will work:

```
-(void)getFacebookUserInfo {
  [self.facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andDelegate:self];
}
```

assuming your `-(void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result` method is available (which it appears that it is).

Note that the full flow of SSO (Single Sign On) is not given here in this post, you'll need to go through https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/#implementsso in detail.

Note also that you may be using a deprecated API for iOS 6, you should look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorial/iossdk/upgrading-from-2.0-to-3.1/ before going further.

Answer (score 1):

With 2.4 api, parameters are used in order to specify which user data items you are interested in receiving.
E.g.:

FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection2 = [[FBSDKGraphRequestConnection alloc] init];

```
FBSDKGraphRequest *selfRequest = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me?"
                                                                   parameters:@{@"fields":@"id,name,first_name,last_name,verified,email"}];
[connection2 addRequest:selfRequest
      completionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *innerConnection, NSDictionary *result, NSError *error) {
          if (error) {
              NSLog(@"%@", error);
              return;
          }

          if (result) {
              // get user data
              NSMutableDictionary *facebookUserData = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:result];
              NSLog(@"result=%@", result);
```

HOWEVER, they apparently messed up big time, as email is NOT CURRENTLY being returned for DEVELOPERS, and currently in development Apps.
Incidentally, it is IMPOSSIBLE to submit bugs on Apps in development, as they require approved apps in the feedback system...

I wonder how do they think we are going to make sure that something works BEFORE submitting an app for approval, or what is the logic of asking for an App Store id of an App which can't be approved BEFORE Facebook integration can be tested to the fullest.

Besides, who is the genius at Facebook who decides to break working code one day from another?

Comment: Hey, I think I just understood where was my problems coming from. Are you sure that if you use a test version, you cannot retrieve the email of the user (I have no version submitted yet, neither in Play Store and iTunes).

Comment: They fixed it shortly after I posted my reply. Now it works, provided you specify the expected values, e.g. "email".

Comment: Ok but when I do a me request, the JSON they return does not contain any email even if I asked the permission for it, but that's not a problem anymore, I used the REST api directly and got all what I needed, I just find it a bit disappointing not to use the SDK

Comment: I have tried right now and it stopped working, AGAIN.
incidentally, if it is an authorization issue, the REST api won't work either

Comment: Hahaha, I made an open graph request if you're interested (it's for Android though with some custom objects but you can have a fair idea of what to do): http://pastebin.com/jprnAqjR

Comment: It started again working, a few hours later. 

The issue is in the horrible quality of the service, not in the iOS layer...
The rest api would fail in the same way, and when I tried debugging it via direct HTTP requests, the result did not change.

Comment: Oh, ok, that's weird, then I made a mistake in the Android Layer because it's working every time I test on Android by using the REST API...

Comment: It is working regularly right now, and has been for some time.